# Magento 2: Remove unused JS from home page

Tags: magento2, javascript, theme, optimization, pagespeed

There are several unused JS files which we do not use on the homepage. JS files are:

> 1. **jquery/ui-modules/datepicker.js**
> 2. **jquery/ui-modules/timepicker.js**
> 3. **moment.js**
> 4. **jquery/ui-modules/sortable.js**
> 5. **jquery/spectrum/spectrum.js**
> 6. **mage/calendar.js**

How can we remove all these unused JS from specific pages like home page.

I tried to remove tag in xml but It did not work. It seems it is added in dependency in jquery-ui

Comment: in which xml file, you have tried

Comment: I tried cms_index_index.xml as well as also checked for view.xml inside theme @Sathishkumar

Comment: basically you can't do that. Because this is requireJS dependency mechanism. You can't remove it when it already required somewhere in the code . The only way that you can determine which file should be call instead call all of it. This mean reduce less js file request to server

Comment: @mrtuvn thanks.. you are right

Comment: @mrtuvn if still we want to remove js then how can we do ?

Comment: @SameerBhayani did you got the solutions ?

Comment: @sumeetbajaj No, I didn't find solution and basically we also can't remove it.

Comment: @SameerBhayani ok